# Load CakePHP forms(views) via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Bascically the average MVC process through CakePHP's MVC workflow goes like this for "add something"

1. call the "add" on our "SomethingController"
2. receive the "add.ctp" (our form)
3. Filling it and posting it back to our "SomethingController"
4. and than reload the "index.ctp" to show up our new "Something"

So in the Controller, it's the `if ($this->request->is('post'))` that tells the controller what to do (giving the form or saving the data).

Here's my problem : I want to make 100% Ajax based application, and when I try to gather the form ("add.ctp"), the controller always get it as a `post` so it never send me my form. Is there a way I can get my form through some Ajax process and then, post the data back to the controller with a `<form>` ?

P.S : I already tried both `$.post` and `$.get` approches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just check the data in the post request?

```
$this->request->data
```

If it's empty, you know you should return a new form. If it's not empty, save it and do whatever else you have to do.

PS - If you don't already know about it, you might also be interested in this function:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax() ) {}
```

to differentiate between  normal and Ajax calls.